# How to render html audio tag in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, plugins, react-native-render-html, render-html

Why is react-native-html-render not rendering html audio tag? Is it possible to do it with this library? Since there is iframe plugin to handle videos and it feels like there should be one to do that with audio but I can not find. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with this library [react-native-render-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html)

Comment: "it feels like there should be" → You can always create a feature request here: https://native-html.canny.io/features ! And I want to remember kindly, "Open Source contributors don't owe you anything". I would love to see the community starting to make some plugins!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **expo-av** libary to play audio within your app (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
       require('./assets/Hello.mp3')
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync(); }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync(); }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Play Sound" onPress={playSound} />
    </View>
  );
}
```